# generating and populating a multi column table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have generated an HTML table using JQuery and want to use a number of span elements inside articles to populate the table.

The table generates both information types over two rows but i need it on the same row as part of a record.

I have tried a hundred things over the past few hours and still cant solve the issue. I have to keep the  tag open to allow the second span to get into the second column but I have to use two loops that way, the other way i came somewhat close to achieving my goal in is below:

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#blockbuster_top_100_films').hide();

    $('#try_this').click(function()
    {                   
          $('#content').append('<table border="1"/>');

          $('table').prepend('<th> Movies </th>', '<th> Description </th>');

          $('span[class="title"], span[class="description"]').each(function()
          {
            $('table').append('<tr><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td></tr>');
          }); 

    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
     <body>
        <input type='button' value='Try this' id='try_this' />


      <section id="blockbuster_top_100_films">
        <article>
          <span class="title">Cowboys &amp; Aliens</span>
          <span class="link">http://www.blockbuster.com:80/catalog/movieDetails/363773</span>
          <span class="description">Based on the graphic novel by Scott Mitchell Rosenberg, Cowboys &amp; Aliens is set in 1800s Arizona, where the local cowboys, headed by gunslinger Jake Lonergan (Daniel Craig), and the indigenous Apache...</span>
          <img src="http://images.blockbuster.com/is/amg/dvd/cov150/drv200/v286/v28605bhsao.jpg?wid=65&amp;&amp;hei=91&amp;cvt=jpeg" />
        </article>
        <article>
          <span class="title">The Change-Up</span>
          <span class="link">http://www.blockbuster.com:80/catalog/movieDetails/483305</span>
          <span class="description">A married father and a swinging single swap bodies after a wild night of drinking, and do their best not to throw each other's lives into complete chaos while scrambling to figure out a way to get...</span>
          <img src="http://images.blockbuster.com/is/amg/dvd/cov150/drv200/v273/v27351ldlup.jpg?wid=65&amp;&amp;hei=91&amp;cvt=jpeg" />
        </article>
        <article>
          <span class="title">Super 8</span>
          <span class="link">http://www.blockbuster.com:80/catalog/movieDetails/486208</span>
          <span class="description">Writer/director J.J. Abrams teams with producer Steven Spielberg for this period sci-fi thriller set in the late '70s, and centering on a mysterious train crash in a small Ohio town. Summer, 1979: a...</span>
          <img src="http://images.blockbuster.com/is/amg/dvd/cov150/drv200/v281/v28148xntyb.jpg?wid=65&amp;&amp;hei=91&amp;cvt=jpeg" />
        </article>
        <article>
          <span class="title">The Hangover Part II</span>
          <span class="link">http://www.blockbuster.com:80/catalog/movieDetails/453672</span>
          <span class="description">A modest bachelor brunch devolves into a wild weekend in Bangkok when the gang travels to Thailand to see Stu get married. Still traumatized by memories of the Las Vegas fiasco, Stu (Ed Helms) vows...</span>
          <img src="http://images.blockbuster.com/is/amg/dvd/cov150/drv200/v275/v27553l0jmg.jpg?wid=65&amp;&amp;hei=91&amp;cvt=jpeg" />
        </article>
</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop around all of the articles instead, and then find the title and description span inside of each article tag:

```
$('article').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var title = $this.find("span.title").text();
    var desc = $this.find("span.description").text();
    $('table').append('<tr><td>' + title + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Both great answers but this one is a little easier to manipulate for what i want to do, one question however, how can i place the image for each article in the table as well?

Comment: add the following line of code inside the loop:

    var $img = $this.find("img");

and then change the last line of the loop to:

    $('table').append('<tr><td>' + title + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>'+$img.outerHTML+'</td></tr>');

Answer (score 1):

You want to be looping through the articles (for each row in the table) rather than the spans.  I've fixed up your loop, you could also loop through the spans for each `<td>` (column) if you want all of them, but in your original code you only had title and description so I've stuck with that.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#blockbuster_top_100_films').hide();

    $('#try_this').click(function()
    {                   
          $('#content').append('<table border="1"/>');

          $('table').prepend('<th> Movies </th>', '<th> Description </th>');

          $('#blockbuster_top_100_films article').each(function(index,el)
          {
             $('table').append('<tr><td>' + $(el).find('.title').text() + '</td><td>' + $(el).find('.description').text() + '</td></tr>');
          });
    });
});
```